# How do I add multiple conditions for a breakpoint in eclipse helios?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I can add a "Conditional" statement to a breakpoint, for instance
`arg0.startsWith("something")`
but i'd like to do something like 
`arg0.startsWith("something") && arg0.endsWith("somethingElse")`

Does anyone have an idea of how this could be done?

Thx, you guys rule!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you have answered your own question.

When you edit the breakpoint properties just put

```
arg0.startsWith("something") && arg0.endsWith("somethingElse")
```

in the 'Conditional' box.

The whole expression is evaluated, think of it as a condition you would put in an `if` statement.

Comment: Ok, are you sure that the execution should have stopped at that condition? Perhaps the string case does not match (startsWith/endsWith are case sensitive)? Try testing it; add a non conditional breakpoint and an expression with your condition and watch its value.

Comment: have you tried the solution you proposed? it doesn't work. and yes i'm sure, because both conditions work separately. the debugger doesn't accept standard java code.

Comment: actually, i was debugging some kind of decompiled code and so the breakpoints were messed up because of that. Your solution (or should i say - even mine) worked.

Comment: Yep, sometimes strange things happen in Eclipse. Glad you got that working :)

Comment: I didn't get this to work if I placed a line break after the `&&`. For some reason, it treats new line characters as different to other whitespace. When I placed my conditional expression all on one line, this worked correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this code to the breakpoint condition.

You can add any code that compiles.

```
Right Click Breakpoint -> Choose Breakpoint Porperties -> Check Conditional -> Paste code
```

Answer (score 1):

Im not quite sure what you are trying to achive. You can write a condition like you did in the latter approach. It will first evaluate the first condition, if that's true the second one will be evaluated. If both are true the condition is a whole is evaulated to true